# How can I make the StartCoroutine working in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm new in c#, and I'm trying to make a platform falling down when the player stand on it. I used StartCoroutine so the platform fall down after five seconds, but for some reason my couroutine doesn't working.

### this is the code:

```
public GameObject player;




   private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

       rb.useGravity = false;

        //rb.isKinematic = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")

        {

            StartCoroutine(ObjectFall());

        }
    }

    IEnumerator ObjectFall()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        Debug.Log("Its working");


        this.rb.useGravity = true;

        //this.rb.isKinematic = true;
    }



}
```

Comment: The code seems to be alright. Did you check if the collision is working? You can do that by also putting a Debug.Log inside OnTriggerEnter().

Comment: What do you mean by `working`? Did you try [debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) in order to see which lines are executed? Is your object tagged correctly? also note: Coroutines are not executed if the component is not `enabled` could this be the case here?

Comment: @KBaker I put Debug.log, but It's not working, and the Debug.Log under the Yield return was working before but now it's not working.

Comment: @derHugo Yes my object tagged correctly. How I can check if the component is not enabled?

Comment: You have to check if the object in the scene has your script as a component and if the blue tick on top left is there.

Comment: @KBaker yes the the object (platform) has the script, and the blue tick on top left is there.

Comment: Is your player a trigger?

Comment: @KBaker The player is not a trigger, I put the trigger above the object (platform), and make it child to the object, and the script is inside the trigger. 
But this is not the problem, the problem was in the object Mass, it was only 1 that’s why the object was falling down when the player stands on it without waiting, so I changed the mass to 10000, and now it's working, the object waits five seconds before it falls.
 I’m not sure if what I did is right or wrong but it’s working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use IEnumerable if you have no parameters for the function. You could use Invoke("ObjectFall", 5) and turn your IEnumerable to void without yield. Its probably not the source of the problem but give it a try. Scale in your game is probably wrong that's why mass 1000 works. Try fixing your scale for the whole scene. Remember 1 unit = 1 meter more or less